# Object API binding : only fetch subobject id

Tags: orientdb

Is it possible to only store the id of subobject as a `String` attribute when retrieve an Object from database with `database.load("objectId")` ?

see documentation here : https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Object-DB-Attach.html

**More informations**

- What I see possible with the documentation but that's not enough for me :

The POJO

```
class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private Address address;
}

class Address {
    @Id
    private String id;

    // Not loaded using lazy loading
    private String city;
}
```

The corresponding built object :

```
{
    "id": "#10:10",
    "address": {
        "id": "#15:2"
    }
}
```

- What I want

POJOs are identical except from `address` field which is a `String` now.

```
class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String address;
}
// I didn't add again the code for Address POJO
```

The sought JSON :

```
{
    "id": "#10:10",
    "address": "#15:2"
}
```

Comment: yes, I think it's possible but try with the latest version of OrientDB

Comment: I'm using v3.0.2, what could you advise me ? I'm editing for more specific information